# Can you get the django form id from django template using id_fieldname?

Tags: django, forms

I am using a model form that has 3 fields - name, country and city. My template looks like this-

```html
<form method="post" id="personForm" data-cities-url="{% url 'ajax_load_cities' %}">
    
    {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
  
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Following this is a bit more jQuery code that fetches the id for the "country" field using a code like this -

```html
$("#id_country").change(function ()....
```

Two things I need to mention here, no where in my code I have id_country except from this jQuery code. Also I haven't set the id attribute for the country field anywhere.

So my question is , is this a thing in django or in jQuery where you can get the id for a field using id_ in front of the field name?

I read the django documentation, haven't seen anything like this.
What am I missing here?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one renders a Django form, it automatically renders an `id` attribute on the form fields. As you noticed this `id` is of the form `id_<field-name>`. This is noted in the documentation in the section [Working with form templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates):

> Note that each form field has an ID attribute set to `id_<field-name>`

Hence you have an `id` as `id_country` because you have a form field named `country`. If you were to have a field named `foo` its id would be `id_foo`.